# How do I get two rows of data when merging queries and the second contains multiple lines

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'm just started working with Webi (4.3) using the universe. I've created two queries using the drag and drop interface and filters and got it to display most of the data I am interested in by merging two queries from different classes(tables). However the issue I have is the second table can contain multiple records for a person and I can't seem to bring my report to display multiple lines in on the report. Example of fields I've selected below

Query 1 contains the following fields in the Staff Table

```
PersonID
FirstName
LastName
MainPostion
```

Query 2 contains the following fields from the SecondaryPositions table

```
PersonID
AlternativePosition
```

I am using a Detail variable (the only thing I can think of) to bring in AlternativePosition from Query2 on the report. However I get a #Multivalue error as a person in Query1 may have more than 1 position in the Query2. Can someone help me figure this so I can see multiple rows in my report if a person has more than 1 AlternativePosition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are really close.

Here is my sample data (top two tables) and merged data with the #MULTIVALUE issue (bottom table).

[image]

In the **Display Settings** section of **Format Table**

[image]

Check the **Avoid duplicate rows aggregation** check box

[image]

And there you have it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I tried this method unfortunately did not work for me, but I think most likely to do with the data I have and not your solution. I'm going to try and write a powerapp/flow to grab the data from both queries and bring them together, manipulate it to the way I want and then 'post' it to the final destination.